# wxWidgets: undefined reference to wxURL

Tags: c++, reference, wxwidgets

When I create a wxURL object I get an undefined reference error:

```
#include <wx/url.h>

....

wxURL url(L"http://site.com/file.txt");

)]+0x8d)||undefined reference to `wxURL::wxURL(wxString const&)'|
)]+0xba)||undefined reference to `wxURL::~wxURL()'|
)]+0x15e)||undefined reference to `wxURL::~wxURL()'|
```

Why might that be?

Comment: Is it only the `wxURL` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile your code, are you linking the corresponding `.cpp` files / libraries (related to `wxURL`) also ? That's essential, because your errors are **link time**.

Comment: You got the point!
You need to link with wxNet (wxbase28_net.lib (release) or wxbase28d_net.lib (debug) ) libraries in order to use wxURL, wxHTTP and other network classes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by linking to the wxNet library.

In CodeBlocks cbp file:

```
<Linker>
    ....
<Add library="libwxbase29u_net.a" />
    ....
</Linker>
```